# Finding a positive definite matrix to satisfy the general equation of an ellipse

Tags: matrices, conic-sections

I am trying to find a matrix A such that $(1)$ can be written as $v^TAv=1$ where $v=(x, y)^T$.

$(1)$: $$\left(\frac{x}{a_1}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{y}{a_2}\right)^2 - 2\left(\frac{xy}{a_1a_2}\right)\cos(\delta)=\sin^2(\delta)$$ $$a_1, a_2, \sin(\delta)\neq 0.$$

I am positive that $\cos(\delta)$ should not be $\cos^2(\delta)$, as it is not even indicated in my textbook's errata.

**Here is my attempt:**

$v^TAv=1 \iff (x,y)A(x,y)^T=1 \iff A [=] 2 $x $2$ $$\iff 1 = (x \ y) \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} \iff 1 = (x \ y) \begin{pmatrix} ax+by \\ cx+dy\end{pmatrix} \iff ax^2 + bxy + cxy + dy^2 = 1 \iff a\sin^2(\delta)x^2 + b\sin^2(\delta)xy + c\sin^2(\delta)xy + d\sin^2(\delta)y^2 = \sin^2(\delta)$$

So, $a\sin^2(\delta)=\frac{1}{{a_1}^2}, d\sin^2(\delta)=\frac{1}{{a_2}^2}, (b+c)\sin^2(\delta)=\frac{-2\cos(\delta)}{a_1a_2}$.

**Where I'm stuck:** Beyond this, I can't seem to separate $b$ and $c$! Is one of them just going to be a free variable?

Thanks.

Comment: You may want your matrix $A$ to be symmetric, so you know that $b=c$? That would at least give you a unique answer.

Comment: Indeed, if $A$ is the quadratic coefficient matrix for an ellipse, then you can indeed assume that it is symmetric, not just positive definite. To see why, note that
$$v^TAv=(v^TAv+v^TA^Tv)/2=v^T(A+A^T)v/2$$
So if you define $B=(A+A^T)/2$, you can see that it will produce the same ellipse, but $B$ is symmetric. Therefore I would assume that $b=c$.